# Kafka continuous rebalancing when slow consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I've been trying to test our Kafka for some negative scenarios and one of them is a very slow consumer. I set `Thread.sleep(15000)` inside my `@KafkaListener` method(it's `spring-kafka`) and set the concurrency to 3. I have 1 topic with 1 partition.
I put 10 messages into the topic and started the service.
When 3 consumers start, they all get to `(Re-)joining group` point,
but then only one of them(let's assume it's `consumer-2`) will get to:

```
Successfully joined group with generation X
```

And start slowly consuming the messages.

(by the way, I use MANUAL_IMMEDIATE Ack mode, but it is reproducible even when I don't add `Acknowledgement` argument to the listener and don't acknowledge messages).
What I see next is as follows:
Up untill all messages are rpocessed by consumer-2, every 3 seconds(default heartbeat interval) I've got a message in the console:

```
AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatResponseHandler: [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=pixel-group] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
```

I wonder why it happens. Only after all 10 messages are processes, there will be another rebalancing after which all 3 consumers will print:

```
Successfully joined group with generation X
```

And one of them will be assigned a partition and there will be no heartbeat problems any longer.
This only happens when I set the sleep interval to a value higher than heartbeat interval. It usually happens once when all consumers are starting, but they will set up successfully shortly afterwards.

**So, to sum it up it seems that:**

If consumer processing time `>` heartbeat interval time - all but first consumer can't finish rebalancing(they probably can't talk to their slow Leader).
What I fail to understand is why this heartbeat error is so persistent?
Why can't the rest of the consumers finish rebalancing somewhere in between Leader's message consumption if the sleep if longer than heartbeat?

**UPDATE**
Kafka version 2.12-2.2.0
Spring-Kafka 2.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: Hi, there are good talks abou the protocol for rebalancing here. As Gary mentioned below you need to align the partitioning of the topic with your instances if you want to scale properly. 
Talks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmLezWRI3Ys

https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-lon19/everything-you-wanted-to-know-kafka-afraid

some docs: 
kip for improvement: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-429%3A+Kafka+Consumer+Incremental+Rebalance+Protocol

Comment: Thanks for the links. I do understand that I need to align the two. But I also want understand how consumers work in terms rebalancing and different timeout options. And as I explained in my experiment, it presents some challenges without obvious answers.

Comment: Yes, I understand. in those talks they go in some details about this, how the consumers work in terms of rebalancing and different configuration options, so if you have time I highly recommend you to watch them.. maybe in high speed up to the point you find interesting for your case.. but there's very valuable information regarding your issue in there. In order to get better answers here I would recommend that you post code and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

> ... concurrency to 3. I have 1 topic with 1 partition ...

You need at least as many partitions as consumers - a partition can only be consumed by one consumer.

What version are you using? Since KIP-62 (Kafka 0.10.1.0), heartbeats are sent in the background by the kafka-clients. So a rebalance should only occur if the listener takes longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`. Google KIP-62 for more information.

**EDIT**

You should see logs like this, while your listener is sleeping...

```
2019-06-13 09:47:52.008 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Heartbeat thread started
...
2019-06-13 09:47:52.072  INFO 61914 --- [           main] com.example.Rbgh664Application           : Sleeping for 15
2019-06-13 09:47:55.120 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-06-13 09:47:55.121 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending HEARTBEAT {group_id=rbgh664,generation_id=45,member_id=source-82297cee-063a-4e0d-89d0-15cfbd6ef680} with correlation id 10 to node 2147483647
2019-06-13 09:47:55.226 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Completed receive from node 2147483647 for HEARTBEAT with correlation id 10, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=0}
2019-06-13 09:47:55.227 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Received successful Heartbeat response
2019-06-13 09:47:58.120 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-06-13 09:47:58.120 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending HEARTBEAT {group_id=rbgh664,generation_id=45,member_id=source-82297cee-063a-4e0d-89d0-15cfbd6ef680} with correlation id 11 to node 2147483647
2019-06-13 09:47:58.225 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Completed receive from node 2147483647 for HEARTBEAT with correlation id 11, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=0}
2019-06-13 09:47:58.226 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Received successful Heartbeat response
2019-06-13 09:48:01.203 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-06-13 09:48:01.204 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending HEARTBEAT {group_id=rbgh664,generation_id=45,member_id=source-82297cee-063a-4e0d-89d0-15cfbd6ef680} with correlation id 12 to node 2147483647
2019-06-13 09:48:01.310 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Completed receive from node 2147483647 for HEARTBEAT with correlation id 12, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=0}
2019-06-13 09:48:01.310 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Received successful Heartbeat response
2019-06-13 09:48:04.285 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-06-13 09:48:04.286 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Sending HEARTBEAT {group_id=rbgh664,generation_id=45,member_id=source-82297cee-063a-4e0d-89d0-15cfbd6ef680} with correlation id 13 to node 2147483647
2019-06-13 09:48:04.390 TRACE 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Completed receive from node 2147483647 for HEARTBEAT with correlation id 13, received {throttle_time_ms=0,error_code=0}
2019-06-13 09:48:04.390 DEBUG 61914 --- [hread | rbgh664] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=source, groupId=rbgh664] Received successful Heartbeat response
20
...
```

Comment: Sorry, will add version. Exactly, hearbeats are in a separate thred, which makes it even more strange. I use latest Kafka.

Comment: A rebalance should not occur if the listener waits for 15 seconds; `max.poll.interval.ms` is 300000 by default. Turn on TRACE logging to see if it gives you more clues.

Comment: Gary, can you elaborate? I did turn on TRACE logging from the beginning and no clue for now. What do you mean by "rebalancing should not occur"? It is occuring when I am starting the service and is not able to finish for all but the first consumer.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; you should see those heartbeat messages which keep the consumer alive while your consumer is not responsive.